# Link of image is not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, link

I added one Image with a link. Now link is showing up in the console but nothing happens when I click on Image.

here is my code

```
<a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}manufacturers-listing/amphenol" target="_self"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/05/slider/amphenol.jpg"}}" /></a>
```

Comment: Where are you adding this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<a href="{{store url="manufacturers-listing/amphenol"}}" target="_self"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/05/slider/amphenol.jpg"}}" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you replace by below code

```
<a href="{{store direct_url=""}}manufacturers-listing/amphenol" target="_self"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/homepage/05/slider/amphenol.jpg"}}" /></a>
```